# Is it possible to edit a table row using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

code

```
<td name="outwardQtyzzz"  align="left" valign="middle" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="rows"> <?=$row->outward;?> </td>
```

or

```
<td name="outwardQtyzzz"  align="left" valign="middle" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="rows"><input name="outwardQtyUpdated" type="hidden" value="" /> <?=$row->outward;?> </td>
```

jquery

```
    var quantity=$("[name=outwardQtyzz]").val($(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(3)').text());
```

I just want to know how to edit a tr in a table using jquery and fetch the edit tr value,by the above jquery i can fetch the value of the tr before editing but after editing i am not able to fetch it  using jquery

Comment: You want to edit a `tr` but you posted a sample of a `td`. It's difficult to identify any problems without a more complete sample.

Comment: you should get the new value just on the same way as you did in your example, only after you completed the edit. What do you use to edit the cells?

Comment: @ManuelvanRijn m confused so i used a input type="text" but not able to fetch the new value

Comment: Then the question is, when do you need to fetch this value? On form submit or something else?

Comment: @ManuelvanRijn  just after entering the new value...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright based on you're comment I think you want to get the value after you lose the focus of the input.

```
$("td.rows input").blur(function() {
  var quantity = $(this).val();
});

// or as of jQuery version 1.7
$("td.rows input").on('blur', function() {
  var quantity = $(this).val();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

yes ...u can edit using .append(),.after(),.before() methods..
Here m putting 1 example...

```
$('#tr').after($(' <input type="text"  style="width:40px;" id="setUnitName"/>'));
```

where '#tr' is table row id,after which u can add textbox using above code,try after(),.before() as well..